# builda static library for iOS for sales

Tags: ios

I would like to know if I build a static library in iOS, can I distribute it (not for free) for other applications that then will be uploaded to the AppStore?
Is there any Apple restriction about this kind of distribution? Note that I am not talking aobut complete framework, but only a static library with header files to be linked together with the target source code.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your code does not access private APIs this shouldn't be a problem. It think the major problem is, how can you prevent piracy.

Comment: thanks. what do you mean by piracy? reverse engineering? if a static library is only a set of binary files and header files, it should be safe enough or maybe not?

Comment: Nah, just what if your lib leaks how do you know someone is using it without you knowing about it? You want money for it right?

Answer (score 1):

You're safe; rationally speaking Apple has no authority over what code you write which happens to work with their device.

If your code does anything which is against Apple's policies, however, your customers are going to be upset when they can't get their apps approved.